# Guardar um dicionário num ficheiro Python

Tags: python, arquivo, dicionário

Tenho uma função que conta quantas vezes surgem as palavras:

```
def countWordExact(dataClean):

    count = {}
    dataFreq = []
    for word in dataClean.split(" "):
        if word in count:
            count[word] += 1
        else:
            count[word] = 1

    dataFreq.append(count)
    return dataFreq
```

Preciso que essa informação seja guardada no ficheiro e para isso faço:

```
    arq = open('novoGuarda.txt', 'w')
    pickle.dump(data, arq)
    arq.close()
```

`data` é equivalente ao `dataFreq`. Vem de outra função daí a mudança de nome.
Com o código acima é criado o ficheiro que invoco, mas guarda desta forma:

```
melancÃ³licarÞ  KX   tivesterß  KX   distraÃ§Ã£orà  KX
```

Que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `pickle` guarda os dados em um formato binário reconhecido somente pelo Python. Isso causa dois problemas com o código que você está usando:

- O modo de abertura do programa deve ser `"wb"`. de "escrita binária"
- O arquivo não será legível, em geral, por um humano quando aberto como arquivo de texto

Fazendo com `pickle`, você faria assim pra escrever:

```
arq = open('novoGuarda.pck', 'wb')
pickle.dump(data, arq)
arq.close()
```

E assim pra ler:

```
arq = open('novoGuarda.pck', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(arq)
arq.close()
```

---

Dito isso, se você quer escrever em um .txt, provavelmente quer que seja legível por um humano.

Para tanto, poderia fazer assim:

```
# Jeito diferente de abrir o arquivo com gerenciador de contexto, mais seguro
with open('novoGuarda.txt', 'w') as arq:
    # Se data é uma lista com somente um dict, como na função
    for key, value in data[0].items():
        arq.write(f'{key} - {value}\n')
```

---

Esse jeito torna o arquivo legível a um humano, mas mais difícil de carregar de volta em outro programa. Pra ter ambos, recomendo que crie um arquivo JSON:

```
import json

...

with open('novoGuarda.json', 'w') as arq:
    json.dump(data, arq)
```

E pra carregar de volta:

```
with open('novoGuarda.json', 'r') as arq:
    data = json.load(arq)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente acrescentar o `encode(encoding='UTF-8')` à linha `arq = open('novoGuarda.txt', 'w')`, ficando assim:

```
arq = open('novoGuarda.txt', 'w').encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```